# QTextDocument: Get content of specific page

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextdocument

Given a `QTextDocument` with a specific width and height, is there a way to get the content of a given page (as plaintext + image URL in case there is an image on the page)  given its page number?

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
QString getTextForPage(int pageNumber); // this is the function I'd like to have
QString getURLForPage(int pageNumber); // this is the function I'd like to have

QString html = R"(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    .summary {page-break-after: always}
  </style>
  <title>title</title>
</head>
  <p class="summary">This is a short summary which would fit into a page</p>
  <p><img src="www.example.com/test.png" height="100" width="200"></p>
  <p><img src"www.example.com/test2.png>" height="50" width="10"</p>
  <p>This is a short text which should fit into a page<p>
<body>

</body>
</html>
)"

const auto width = 100;
const auto height = 200;
auto textDoc = new QTextDocument();
textDoc->setHtml(html);
textDoc->setPageSize(QSizeF {wide, height});
textDoc->setDocumentMargin(0);

for (auto curPageNum = 1; curPageNum <= textDoc->pageCount(); ++curPageNum) {
    qDebug() << "current page: " << curPageNum;
    qDebug() << getTextForPage(curPageNum);
    qDebug() << getURLForPage(curPageNum);
}
```

This should print:

```
1
This is a short summary which would fit into a page
(empty string as there is no URL)
2
(empty string as the there is no text on the page)
www.example.com/test.png
3
This is a short text which should fit into a page
www.example.com/test2.png
```

In general, the text in the p tags can span multiple pages, and the images are guaranteed to span at most one page,in case that helps.

Comment: The concept of "page" in the sense you mean only really applies to printed document. So you need to print the document (even if it's just inside the application and invisible to user). So research Qt printing.

Comment: @hyde: I'd challenge that idea. The concept of the page is independent of printing, it's primarily related to how the Scribe framework lays out the document.

Comment: Seeing the comments here and there, is it possible then to bring up a suitable demo example for the case?

Comment: @MohammadKanan: What exactly would you need in the example to help answer the question? The code which renders the page on a widget or QQuickPaintedItem?

Comment: merely the content you are rendering .. the actual position you are trying to catch. if that is _possible_ thanks.

Comment: @MohammadKanan: Done, please ask if there is still something unclear.

Comment: Excellent, lets see.

Comment: @Inkane Well, we probably mean the same thing. I meant "printing" as synonym to creating concrete layout here. I don't think there's a "light version" of laying out a document, which doesn't effectively produce same result as printing to a digital PDF/PS-like format which doesn't require rendering actual pixels.

Comment: Why would each paragraph be on a new page? If that's your design requriement, it will be easier to simply parse the html.

Comment: @dtech: Maybe the small example text misled you, but as I wrote,"In general, the text in the p tags can span multiple pages", and to clarify, a page can contain multiple p tags.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to get the content of a specific page as "plaintext + image URL". Qt does not support that. Specially when you set the content as html, Qt won't extract a sub-html document for you...

What you can get is the content as an image (or a pdf), by using a `QPrinter` and requesting to print only a specific page. I can post code showing how to do so if that could be an acceptable solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I need. I already render the paginated text on a QQuickPaintedItem using QTextDocument::drawContents, and now I'm just trying to find the position in the text for a specified page.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt Qt API will let you get that information.